# A page URL on XAMPP to show a URL without xampp folder

Tags: php, xampp

A friend set up a linux box for me with XAMPP on it.
I updated a DNS records for a domain I own (example.com lets say) to point to IP of the box.
Now, when I browse to www.example.com (it has index.php in xampp folder) it automatically shows 
www.example.com/xampp in address bar.

Question - can something be done so that I keep using xampp folder as a landing 
folder for the domain, yet the URL will show a plain www.example.com URL?
Thank you

Comment: Yes setup a Virtual Host for your site

Comment: RiggsFolly, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are multiple solutions. The most easy one would be to move the index.php one folder up (into the folder where the xampp folder is). That way your script would be directly reachable via the domain/index.php or even just domain/ if the directory index is activated.

If that's not working for some reason you can change the document root of the apache (the folder where your website should be put into). Look for a line like

```
DocumentRoot /some/path/here
```

in the Apache configuration. It might be directly inside the apache2.conf or in a sub folder inside a virtual host file (e.g. 000-default.conf). Change the path in there to the folder you want to use for your website.

Please take care. Messing with your server config can have side effects on other domains hosted there.